# Pandas color bar chart based off dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm still rather new to Pandas, and was unable to relate similar problems asked here with what I have.
I have 3 columns: `country, mean, income` stored in the dataframe.

I'm able to create a horizontal bar chart where countries as labeled on the Y axis, and the mean is listed on the X axis. The income field has 4 possible values, and I would like to color each bar based off those values. I'm currently plotting with this and I am not sure how to use the `income` field to change the color of each bar depending on the income value

```
df.sort_values(by=['mean']).plot.barh(x='country', y='mean')
```

Comment: Please, can you update your post with a sample of your dataframe (`df.head(10)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.barh.html), you can pass the optional argument `color` to `barh()`

```
color: str, array-like, or dict, optional
```

with `array-like` being

```
A sequence of color strings referred to by name, RGB or RGBA
code, which will be used for each column recursively....
```

So you can take your dataframe, create a list mapping each row in the plotted dataframe (including the sorting you do) to colors depending on the value of the `income` column and pass that as `color` argument.

**Example:**
Sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ["DE", "US"], 'mean': [0.1, 0.2] , 'income': ['value1', 'value2'] })
```

```
color_list = df.sort_values(by=['mean'])['income'].map('value1':'red', 'value2':'blue'}).tolist()
```

and

```
df.sort_values(by=['mean']).plot.barh(x='country', y='mean', color=color_list)
```

Output image

[image]